# Raspberry PI 3 model B через ноутбук

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, hdmi

Как работать с Raspberry PI 3 model B через ноутбук, то есть , чтобы вместо windows появилась ОС которая находится на Raspberry PI 3 model B?Соответственно подключаю Raspberry PI 3 model B к ноутбуку через HDMI кабель

Comment: не ноутбук подключайте, а монитор, мышь и клавиатуру. ноутбуки не умеют «прикидываться» набором перечисленных устройств.

Comment: а если нет монитора при себе нет никаких способов использовать ноутбук как просто монитор?

Comment: насколько мне известно, ни один *обычный* ноутбук не умеет «прикидываться» набором перечисленных устройств. впрочем, как и ни один *обычный* компьютер/планшет/нетбук/смартфон/и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, Ага, а X11 протокол придумали просто так. Я уверен, что вы не правы в данном случае.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не ноутбук подключайте, а монитор, мышь и клавиатуру. ноутбуки не умеют «прикидываться» набором перечисленных устройств.